# Added cert and key files in newman js file but still i could see error messages

Tags: node.js, postman, newman, postman-collection-runner

I would need to add certificate and key inside the newman's .js file. Please advise.

Below is my sample (modified) code,

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
const newman = require('newman');
    newman.run({
        collection: require("/Users/cloud/Documents/sample.json"), // can also provide a URL or path to a local JSON file.
        environment: require("/Users/cloud/Documents/env.json"),
        insecure: true,
        sslClientCert: fs.readFileSync("/Users/cloud/Documents/certs/test.crt"),
        sslClientKey: fs.readFileSync("/Users/cloud/Documents/certs/test.key"),
        reporters: 'htmlextra',
        reporter: {
            htmlextra: {
                export: '/Users/cloud/Documents/report', // If not specified, the file will be written to `newman/` in the current working directory.
                darkTheme: true, // optional, tells the reporter to use the `Dark Theme` template
                title: 'My new report title'
            }
        }
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {throw err;}
        console.log('collection run 8 complete!');
    });
```

I have added the cert and key file and i still get SSL handshake error. But when i run in newman using below command it works. I am not able to pass the client key and client cert in js file

```
newman run "collectio.json" -e "env.json" --insecure --ssl-client-key <keypath> --ssl-client-cert <cert path>
```

Below is the error message i see in html report, but it works well in newman CLI,

```
Assertion: 

write EPROTO 4514592192:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1536:SSL alert number 40

Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
```

In my collection snippet i have used,

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
console.log(jsonData);
pm.globals.set("JWT", jsonData.access_token);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the following options (`sslClientCert` and `sslClientKey`) within the `Newman` run object:

```
newman.run({
        collection: require("/Users/cloud/Documents/sample.json"), // can also provide a URL or path to a local JSON file.
        environment: require("/Users/cloud/Documents/env.json"),
        insecure: true,
        sslClientCert: fs.readFileSync("/Users/cloud/Documents/certs/test.crt"),
        sslClientKey: fs.readFileSync("/Users/cloud/Documents/certs/test.key"),
        reporters: 'htmlextra',
        reporter: {
            htmlextra: {
                export: '/Users/cloud/Documents/report', // If not specified, the file will be written to `newman/` in the current working directory.
                darkTheme: true, // optional, tells the reporter to use the `Dark Theme` template
                title: 'My new report title'
            }
        }
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {throw err;}
        console.log('collection run 8 complete!');
    });
```

Comment: Hi Danny, As suggested, i have given a try. Now i could see the very first request is passing and i could see no response in the body report. However when i hit from postman the same request is passing and even when i run in newman (without report generation), the requests are passing. Only when is use the .js (code above) fails. Not working as expected. Kindly advise

Comment: i have modified the content and provided more data. Could you please look into and advise.